# MAMP - Wont serve Javascript with full stops in file name

Tags: javascript, apache, mamp

Since forever MAMP has been working correctly but today I have noticed that it is refusing to serve certain JS files to the browser.

A filename of say file.js will be served if requested but file.min.js will not be served, with apache logging the error as a 403 (client denied by server configuration).

Nothing has changed within my configuration so I am wondering what has happened here.

By browsing to the /js folder with Options All enabled, the same thing is occuring, the browser will display all relevant .js files as long as there is no second fullstop within the name so file.js will be displayed but file.1.2.js will not neither would file.anything.js

Any ideas as to what causes this?

Update:  .htaccess exists in the web root to use a directory/file if it exists otherwise it redirects the request to index.php

```
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Comment: *"Nothing has changed within my configuration"* ~ I can almost guarantee that this is not true

Comment: What about your operating system, filesystem permissions, etc? I'd have a look at the directories in question in your terminal. Note any differences in the permissions mask between files that are served and those that are not

Comment: I am running OSX 10.10.14, each file is owned by the same user that the apache process runs under.  To rule out file permissions themselves I did manually set permissions to 0777 to ensure there is no access being blocked by the filesystem itself.  Manually changing a file name and doing a directory listing in the web browser will replicate the issue I am seeing.  Removing any additional fullstop in the file name will cause apache to list/serve the item but it stops as soon as there is another fullstop in the filename.

Comment: Try using a different browser or running a curl command for the directory listing (`curl -v "http://localhost/path/to/js/folder"`). It could be your browser / add-ons

Comment: yep I am seeing the same output in all browsers tested Chrome v44, FF v33.1, Safari 8.0.7.

I am fairly sure this is an apache thing but unsure of where to look for how apache is configured to serve files.

Comment: What about curl? It's worth checking. Otherwise, trawl through the Apache config files for `Allow` or `Deny` keywords

Comment: Curl is just showing a redirect (I am guessing this is based on the .htaccess posted above), I guess I will begin to go through the MAMP/Apache conf to find out whats happening.  I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: That'll be the directory redirect. You can set curl to follow it via `curl -L` or just make sure the URI ends in a slash, eg `http://localhost/path/to/js/`

Comment: well I did not have time to check this over the weekend but can confirm Curl is showing the same as the browser.  Time to go through the apache config I guess.

Comment: update: the apache mime.types file appears to be corrupted, viewing it within vim or any other editor looked fine but applying a new version has resolved the issue.  Not sure what would have corrupted this file but its good to have it resolved.